# how to select field name where value is matched

Tags: php, mysql

[image: table with fields]

Here the given image is of my table. is it possible to select that field which have value false and id=2. like when i pass the id=2 it should return the field name sun.

Comment: first clear the question

Comment: SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE sun = 'false' will return 2,10,12 . You can add another where condition for id field

Comment: @vikramsharma I think OP wants sth like `SELECT (the row that is false) FROM tbl WHERE id=2`

Answer (score 3):

You can use `case` statements and `concat_ws()`:

```
select id,
       concat_ws(',',
                 (case when sun = 'false' then 'sun' end),
                 (case when mon = 'false' then 'mon' end),
                 (case when tue = 'false' then 'tue' end),
                 (case when wed = 'false' then 'wed' end),
                 (case when thu = 'false' then 'thu' end),
                 (case when fri = 'false' then 'fri' end),
                 (case when sat = 'false' then 'sat' end)
                )
from table t
where id = 2;
```

Comment: thank you so much it helps me lot.now the question is from wich name i can fetch that value sun in mysql.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN sun = 'false' then 'sun' END
            WHEN mon = 'false' then 'mon' END
            WHEN tue = 'false' then 'tue' END
            WHEN wed = 'false' then 'wed' END
            WHEN thu = 'false' then 'thu' END
            WHEN fri = 'false' then 'fri' END
            WHEN sat = 'false' then 'sat' END
        END AS MyColumn
FROM MyTable
WHERE id = 2
```